# How can I create a feature that shows if someone has made a comment or not?

Tags: python, data-science, feature-engineering

I am using [this dataset from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/osmi/mental-health-in-tech-survey).

There is a column which shows which respondents made a comment and which respondents did not make a comment. The respondents that did not make a comment have a NaN value. I want to create another variable that shows 1 if someone made a comment and 0 if someone did not make a comment. This is the code I have used:

```
for i in df['comments']:
    if i==np.nan:
        return 0
    elif i!=np.nan:
        return 1
```

However, I get the following error:

> `return` outside function.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since this code contains `return` it should be used inside a function, you cannot use return outside a fucntion. Also instead of loops try using the `apply()` function of pandas

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will helps you!!!

```
import numpy as np

def fun():
    m = 0 if i is np.nan else 1
    return m

for i in data["comments"]:
    new = fun()
    print(new)
```